# MicroPython PyCharm 2021.3.3 plugin permission error

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, raspberry-pi-pico

I was trying to set up MicroPython on PyCharm 2021.3.3, unfortunately I was not able to successfully connect my board to IDE. I'm getting trying to use tools>>MicroPython>>MicroPython REPL:

```
Found the device, but could not connect via port 'COM4': could not open port 'COM4': PermissionError(13, 'Odmowa dostępu.', None, 5)
I'm not sure what to suggest. :-(
Press ENTER to continue
```

Then I have tried to flush simple program to control despite previous error and it spits out:

```
Connecting to COM4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\reczul\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm2021.3\plugins\intellij-micropython\scripts\microupload.py", line 139, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\Users\reczul\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm2021.3\plugins\intellij-micropython\scripts\microupload.py", line 56, in main
    board = Pyboard(port)
  File "C:\Users\reczul\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\ampy\pyboard.py", line 147, in __init__
    raise PyboardError('failed to access ' + device)
ampy.pyboard.PyboardError: failed to access COM4
```

What can I do to fix this error?

The sample code I have used:

````
from machine import Pin, Timer

led = Pin(25, Pin.OUT)
tim = Timer()
def tick(timer):
    global led
    led.toggle()

tim.init(freq=2.5, mode=Timer.PERIODIC, callback=tick)```
````

Comment: Are you sure the device is using COM4? Two ways to check, 1) windows > 'device manager' > Ports (COM & LPT) > unplug device > plug it back in > see which port disappeared and reappeared. 2) windows > 'cmd' >  type the command 'mode'. Let me know how you go and we can go from there.

Comment: How were you able to access Tools > MicroPython REPL? My PyCharm 2022 and 2021 do not have a 'Tools' menu, but IntelliJ does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming you are using a Pi Pico.**

You are most likely getting this error because you pressed the 'BOOTSEL' button while plugging your device in.

Drag your UF2 file onto the device, it should reboot.
**Don't** unplug the device and hold the 'BOOTSEL' this time.

It should be good to go now.